# dynamics 365 change default from field in email

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I'm looking to change the default from user when an email is created. Setting it through a workflow doesn't work, and business rules does not allow to set the default from behavior. Has anyone been able to do this successfully?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think it would benefit others even more if you could post your suggestion as a single question and give your solution as a separate answer.

Comment: Thanks @LazerBass! I updated to the format you suggested!

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer by stringing together a few different answers. Note:  I couldn't find any documentation on official Microsoft Dynamics functionality, so although it worked for me on version 8 of Dynamics 365 (cloud) it could stop working in the future.

I created a javascript file that ran on load. If the form had form state, create, then I would use the following script to change the value:

```
function _setFromUser() {
    var legalQueueID = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
    var recordName = "Legal Contracts Queue";
    var entityName = "queue";
    Xrm.Page.getControl("from").getAttribute().setValue([{ id: legalQueueID, name: recordName, entityType: entityName }]);
}
```

Hope this helps someone else!